# Force function calls of a class to use await (without writing it)

Tags: python-asyncio

I'd like to convert some code I have already to be using async IO calls but I do not wish to have to find all the function calls and add the `await` keyword.

I already have a way to convert functions of a class to async with a decorator.

Now I would like to know if there is a way to "decorate" every function call with "await".

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def f1(self):
        self.f2()

    async def f2(self):
        pass
```

Can a "decorator" or other method be used to force `self.f2()` to be interpreted as `await self.f2()`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Second thing: putting 'async' keyword in front of a method does nothing, without changing the method itself to make use of asynchronous features (which imply calling and awaiting asynchronous functions itself).

really: it does nothing, but given a false perception of possible-asynchronous concurrency, but with methods that are actually blocking.

Seriously. So much, I will just write again: automatically plugging `async def` in a synchronous method does not change it to work as a collaborative asynchronous co-routine, and it is actually harmful.

That is the most fundamental difference when running async code: whenever something should give time for concurrent async tasks to work, they have to be awaited.

Now that we went through the short answer, there is a way that probably would work - but instead of making each method  `async` it would make each method instead, run in an thread pool executor - that would fire all those methods to run in background, but without the `await`in the caller, there would be no way to get the return value back to were the call took place. It happens that the `await` syntax is actually the most confortable way of getting something running in the background allowing concurrency, and re-start from where the call was made once the results is available. The developers of the Python language took 20+ years to get at this design, actually - you are just asking for it to be undone: it would be easier to spend some more time working on your tooling, and substitute all the calls to the "now async" methods, really.

Now, that **all** said, yes, there could be a way to "fake" the decorated methods to be async, and actually yield to the asynchronous loop (while they execute in a separate thread) - so that a synchronous function would *behave* like an async task being awaited.  (forget the "async prefixing" - besides doing nothing, the only way of getting the result value is by actually running `await` on a call to them).

That would require you to submit the original function as a task to run in other-thread, with a call to `asyncio.run_in_executor`, or, maybe, more by more directly creating a normal concurrent.futures Future and adding a done callback, but, besides that, a second step is needed: you'd need to "jump into" the asyncio loop execution from the sync function. That is not easy to do - I can't think of a consistent way to do that, but probably there is a possible hack - and most of all: the loop is designed so that it is running the code in whatever task called your "converted" method first. It is not made to be "re-entrant" - so, when you jump back into it, (say, by forcing a call to loop._run_once), it will get into an inconsistent state, and just break.

Perhaps there could be another approach modifying the code in the calling task itself, so that the `await` op is included - that is also *hard* to do and complex.

All in all, and since your approach is meaningless from the beginning (As it would not improve anything), I suggest to desist, and just convert your code manually, if it really needs to be async.

Comment: I am not trying to undo what async IO is bringing. I'm trying to convert my existing code that until now was happy running in synchronous mode. This code is made of a few thousand calls to functions so as i'm lazy i don't want to have to put `await` in thousand locations and was looking for an easy way to convert all the calls to be asynch. Thanks for your answer, i understand the point.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following library which is very convenient in this cas (i.e. when you don't want to have to convert your thousand lines of calls in your existing code to have async/await):
https://github.com/oremanj/greenback

Using this library i am able to re-enter an asynch "state" from a synchronous function. That serves the seeked purpose very well and does not require any code change in existing code.

Comment: yes  - great find! I confess that while writing my long text in the other answer  I was trying to think of a way of doing something similar. Very clever library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).